# validity of facebook page whther it really exists and its url structure

Tags: php, regex, facebook, facebook-page

I have spent a couple of hours on how to validate Facebook PAGES. I found and read lot of articles/posts but did not find something that matches my requirement. I wanted to convert a user input url ($rawurl) into a format that I want ($goodurl) and on googling, i found regex is the way to do it but it is very complicated and difficult to understand and need help.

The user can enter URL the way he/she likes 
example:

```
http://facebook.com/WillSmith, 
https://facebook.com/WillSmith, 
http://www.facebook.com/WillSmith, 
https://www.facebook.com/WillSmith, 
www.facebook.com/WillSmith 
or just facebook.com/WillSmith
```

Or any other way. Not only this, other than the vanity url format, the facebook pages also comes with other format like facebook.com/pages/usernames/somenumbers. Subdomains such as en-gb.facebook.com makes things more difficult. So after googling more, I found a regex `http[s]?://(www|[a-zA-Z]{2}-[a-zA-Z]{2})\.facebook\.com/(pages/[a-zA-Z0-9\.-]+/[0-9]+|[a-zA-Z0-9\.-]+)[/]?$` but not sure if it will take care of all the above conditions.

Help what I need:
1. The standard format I need is `https://www.facebook.com/WillSmith`
2. I also need to check if it is a valid URL. eg.the above url is valid and if you see this url `https://www.facebook.com/WillSmith555`, it fits the valid criteria but there is no such page on Facebook. It says "Sorry, this page isn't available.  The link you followed may be broken, or the page may have been removed" with a broken thumbsup picture.

After checking these two criteria, I need an echo in the php file whether the url entered by user is valid or invalid after doing a regex conversion.

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do a head only request do facebook:

```
<?php

    function header_req( $url )
    {
        $channel = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($channel, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($channel, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10);
        curl_setopt($channel, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
        curl_setopt($channel, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
        curl_setopt($channel, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);
        curl_setopt($channel, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($channel, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; rv:2.2) Gecko/20110201');
        curl_setopt($channel, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
        curl_setopt($channel, CURLOPT_IPRESOLVE, CURL_IPRESOLVE_V4);
        curl_setopt($channel, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
        curl_setopt($channel, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE); 
        curl_exec($channel);
        $httpCode = curl_getinfo( $channel, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE );
        curl_close($channel);
        return $httpCode;
    }

    $url = "https://www.facebook.com/WillSmith";

    //lets check the url for facebook as host:


    // 1 add http if not found in URL
    if ( stripos( $url , "http") !== 0)
        $url = "http://" . $url;


    // 2 get facebook.com from URL
    $host = parse_url( $url, PHP_URL_HOST );

    // 3 if host is indeed facebook.com then continue
    if ( stripos( $host , "facebook.com" ) )
    {
        $response = header_req($url);

        if ( $response === 200 || $response === 302 )
            echo "Page Found";
        else
            echo "Page Not Found";
    }

?>
```

Advantages of this :

1. It will get only headers of the page which will be around 1KB - 5 KB.
2. NO use of Regexp.
3. All pages are verified whatever the pattern is :)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I do not see any mention of facebook.com domain within the function so i am assuming that the function will declare google.com also as page found. I wanted Page Found echo only if the fuction finds a valid facebook page that exist irrespective of how the url is written.

Comment: @Sabha you can check if the URL contains specific string like Facebook.com :)

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the regexp :

- You need to escape the slashes with a backslash
- A few modifications to match all your examples

Your regexp, modified :

```
^(http[s]?:\/\/)?((www|[a-zA-Z]{2}-[a-zA-Z]{2})\.)?facebook\.com\/(pages\/[a-zA-Z0-9\.-]+\/[0-9]+|[a-zA-Z0-9\.-]+)\b[\/]?$
```

demo : http://regex101.com/r/lN1tN6/1

Comment: No the only way to know if the page exists is to try to open it and see if you get an error... (The script in Ancient geek's answer)

Comment: Thank you Sly. I am trying to understand the expression. Is there a way to find within the expression if the page exists on facebook? Also if someone enters a raw url, how can i convert it into a valid url and put that url in the $goodurl variable as asked in the question? Thanks.

Comment: The problem is that, the url may be valid. I guess the innerhtml needs to be checked for the string "Sorry, this page isn't available" not sure how to check that.

Comment: Is there a way to replace entered url in a specific format in same textbox on losing focus using this expression? OR just change the variable value with the correct format? For example, I need my url to start with https :// www . followed by the pagename removing all junk characters after the "?" sign. 1..https://www.facebook.com/username?ref=ts&fref=ts will become https://www.facebook.com/username 2..facebook.com/username will become https://www.facebook.com/username 3..https://www.facebook.com/pages/username/123456789?ref=br_rs will become https://www.facebook.com/pages/username/123456789

Comment: something like <input type="text" id="fb" onblur="myFunction()">
and <script>
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("fb");
    x.value = x.value.replace( [your regexp] , [replace] );
}
</script>